# Python: Indexing error only in flask routes.py, not anywhere else

Tags: python, flask

I am using os.walk() to get the paths of files from a directory. my code works fine when I use it in utils.py, but once I put it in the index() function in routes.py I get IndexError: list index out of range, when trying to grab the names from the list.

utils.py

```
menu_image_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('static/img/menu/'):
    for filename in files:
        x = os.path.join(root, filename)
        menu_image_list.append(x)

print(menu_image_list[0])
```

output: static/img/menu/image_1.jpg

routes.py

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    # Handling Twitter

    # Handling image file names
    menu_image_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('static/img/menu/'):
        for filename in files:
            x = os.path.join(root, filename)
            menu_image_list.append(x)

    menu_image1 = menu_image_list[0]
    menu_image2 = menu_image_list[1]
    menu_image3 = menu_image_list[2]
    menu_image4 = menu_image_list[3]

    # Handling email contact form


    return render_template('index.html', image1=menu_image1, image2=menu_image2, image3=menu_image3, image4=menu_image4)
```

I have removed irrelevant code in routes.py but kept the comments to explain why i am using ['GET', 'POST']

so I assume this is an issue with flask... I also tried to turn this code into a class and import it from utils.py as a class, but that did not work. I also tried just importing the list from flask, that also did not work. They each gave the same error.

Comment: Have you tried printing the entire `menu_image_list` in both to see its contents? In utils.py you only retrieve the first item, but in routes.py you retrieve 4 items. Also, are you running the two scripts from the same working directory (that will make a difference because relative paths)?  [it's not an issue with flask]

Comment: @swalladge Thank you for your reply... I have been told to print from routes.py before but I do not know how... how could I do that? when i try to do it in the terminal i get an error regarding importing from another file, when i go to localhost i get the indexerror.... perhaps I am missing something

Comment: @swalladge they are in the same dir!

Comment: @swalladge okay I figured it out... I placed the for loop and print function above most of the imports and I was able to print out the paths of the files. but it still does not work inside the function index()

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there were a few problems that were causing this issue.

1. My project layout was incorrect. If you are having this problem check these two links:
   http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/layout/
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44PvX0Yv368
2. I made the path for os.walk() start in the parent directory of what was written prior

2.5 this may cause issues if you try to os.path.join the path used in os.walk() and the filename (result of os.walk()) when you try to add these paths to html because you will be one directory higher than you need to for html (sorry if this is confusing to you, it is to me as well). For some reason, os.walk() wants to see one more directory than html, so instead of recycling the path from os.walk(path) you should do this:

```
menu_image_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('siamsite/static/img/menu/'):
    for filename in files:
        x = os.path.join('static/img/menu/', filename)
        menu_image_list.append(x)
return render_template('index.html', 
                       image1=menu_image_list[0], image2=menu_image_list[1],
                       image3=menu_image_list[2], image4=menu_image_list[3])
```

I hope this helps someone, if you need further elaboration, let me know!